# Como usar caracteres de escape em uma string em C#?

Tags: c#, string, regex, arquivo

Não estou conseguindo escanear um arquivo que contém os caracteres EICAR (Arquivo de teste padrão para métodos de escaneamento de antivírus), por conter caracteres de escape tais como "\", "()", "[]". Preciso de uma ajuda para identificar esses caracteres no meu programa como sendo normais dentro de uma *string*, como outros comuns como "a", "b", "1", "2", etc. 
Segue o código abaixo:

```
string[] Lista = new string[] { "X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*"};

string dir = @"C:\Program Files (x86)";

private void btnScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   List<string> busca= Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.dll*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();                  
   foreach (string item in busca)
   {                                              
     StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(item);
     string ler = stream.ReadToEnd();
            foreach (string st in Lista)
            {
              if (Regex.IsMatch(ler, st))
              {
                btnDelete.Visible = true;
                btnQuarentena.Visible = true;
              }                             
            }
   }
}
```

Já tentei colocar a *string* EICAR desse modo, porém não adiantou:

```
string[] Lista = new string[] { @"X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*"};
```

O Visual Studio sempre me retorna o mesmo erro, de *escape sequence*, afetado pelos caracteres "\", "[]" e "()".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe um problema aí. Você está tentando ler um arquivo que é essencialmente um binário como se fosse um texto. Isto não vai dar certo. Você precisa usar a classe [`BinaryReader`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1). Alternativamente pode usar o [`File.ReadAllBytes()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_File_ReadAllBytes_System_String_).

```
byte[] array = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\programa.exe");
```

Você vai jogar o conteúdo em um *buffer* que nada mais é que um *array* de `byte`s (`byte[]`) com o método [`ReadBytes()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_BinaryReader_ReadBytes_System_Int32_). Desta forma qualquer caractere é permitido.

Um *byte array* permite muitas das operações permitidas em *strings*, afinal uma *string* no fundo é um *array* de caracteres. Evidentemente não dá para usar RegEx nele. Talvez por sorte, assim vai conseguir mais eficiência a praticar o uso de técnicas brutas.

```
var path = @"C:\programa.exe"
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(path);
//não é muito elegante, pode dar problema em casos extremos
//mas tentar carregar arquivos inteiros na memória sempre pode dar problema
//truque para ler todos os bytes até o final
byte[] buffer = reader.ReadBytes((int)new FileInfo(path).Length));
reader.Close();
```

Existe a alternativa de converter o conteúdo para Base64 e jogar em uma *string*. Mas duvido que você vá conseguir fazer algo útil com isto.

Também existe a alternativa de ler o arquivo com *stream* genérico bruto:

```
var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\programa.exe", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] buffer= new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
fs.Close();
```

Note que eu fiz o acesso de forma não recomendada seguindo a linha do que você já havia feito. O ideal é usar o *statement* `using` que garante o fechamento do *stream* quando ele terminar sua operação. Assim:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\programa.exe", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read)) {
    byte[] buffer= new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/ReadText.cs)